Sign out of Microsoft Entra Id Account in Desktop App using Msal
i am implementing MFA using entra Id (dot net Desktop App). Now when i try to logout, i am using this code
                var accounts = await publicClient.GetAccountsAsync();
              
                var account =  accounts?.FirstOrDefault()
                   
                if (account != null)
                {                   
                    //
                    // Remove the specific signed-in account from the cache
                    //
                    await publicClient.RemoveAsync(account);
                }


The issue is that i expect it to logout from that account, but it seems that it is only deleting MSAL's cache of that user and their tokens, but it doesn't seem like it's actually signing the user out. If I try to log in to my app again, my previous user will show up as "signed in" and clicking will log me in as that user without having to provide credentials again
